# How can I transfer the listed NFTs (artworks) to null address?

Tags: scam, burn

My wallet was recently hacked by a scammer, there's a sweeper bot transferring all the funds I send to my wallet to the hacker's wallet. I'm an artist and I have several artworks minted and listed with this wallet, they're still stucked there, and I'd like to know if there's any possibility to make them inaccessible for anybody so that I could remint these artworks with my new wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use The Interceptor to rescue the assets if they are on Ethereum mainnet, check https://youtu.be/LxoHUUUN_XI

If they are on some other network, I recommed flashbots white hat service

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. It is better to include the main ideas in the answer and only use the link to expand the details.

Answer (score 0):

If it's burnable, yes. Usually transfer function doesn't allow transfers for address zero but there's exceptions.